# Android ListPreference visual tweak

Tags: android, listpreference

Is it possible to get the ListPreference in Android so that each of the items in the list has two rows of text per option, not just the one that is usually seen.

WHat I am after is a little bit like this : https://wiggio.zendesk.com/attachments/token/0uwzbehz5cnkrsu/?name=Picture_12.png

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to make a custom object that extends `ListPreference`. It doesn't have that capability out of the box.

Comment: Hmm - I was afraid that was going to be the answer :-)

Comment: custom ListPreference was the way to go, very much based on this http://www.cmwmobile.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=12 with a fix or two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom ListPreference was the way to go, very much based on this cmwmobile.com/… with a fix or two